# How to fix angular http post not waiting for pyramid backend response

Tags: angular, pyramid

I build angular using ng build --prod.

Output is into a static folder in pyramid backend

on a login form, a button is clicked, and then angular makes http post to pyramid backend.
pyramid backend receives username and pw. generates jwt token and sends response.

Angular is not waiting for response.

Angular makes http post using subscribe and map() w/ observable.

creating a jwt takes 3 seconds or so. If i don't choose not to make a jwt and return json super quick from backend, angular catches it right away.

If pyramid backend doesn't respond fast enough, the subscribed won't catch data, or errors. it seems as if nothing is executed in the call back functions of subscribe because it is as if it unsubscribed right away.

If pyramid doesn't respond due to which ever issues, then an error is caught right away from the subscribe call back and it shows in developer console log.

Attempted to:
I've tried switching to async, same issue.
I fixed angular not handeling routing by outpush hash true for routing.

This is what the code looks like.

login.component.ts

```
login_button_pressed(username, password){
  console.log('Seen in console .log');
  this.auth.login(username, password)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe( data => {
     //do something with data },
   error => {
     //print error  
  });
   console.log(login function ended);
}


//pseudo code style.
```

auth.ts

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<user> {
    console.log('This is printed in developer console log');
    return this.http.post<any>('/route', {username, password})
    .pipe(map( returned_data => {

     console.log('this is never executed even though i see backend); 
     console.log('processing the two passed strings')
     //do something with returned data

     return returned_data
  });
}
```

in the pyramid backend, I print the received strings and print to console in backend before sending response.

Print commands i talk about are there for debugging purposes

Comment: Try using `take(1)` instead of `first()`

Comment: Just tried it. same results. 
console.log('seen in console .log) is shown in browser console.
Then it goes straight to console.log(login function ended)

Then 2 seconds later, the python terminal back-send says sending response.

Comment: I remember when I was debugging a routing issue,

Angular was not handling the routing. Pyramid would serve angular's index.html in static folder, but after a redirect somewhere, Pyramid would handle routing and angular would not.


I added { useHash: true}

to appRoutingModule when initializing it to look like this
      
         export const appRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})

I have been looking for other commands to hopefully solve my issues in regards to asynchronous commands and production builds.

no luck so far.

Comment: Do you see the request being canceled from network tab in chrome dev tools ?

Comment: No requests are canceled. I do see the POST request from angular front end to pyramid backend in the pyramid debug toolbar  for resolving login.

Angular is not waiting. I tried making login_button_pressed an async and wait on a promise. Still same issue, but   console.log(login function ended); doesnt display when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on [mdn asynchronous call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests). Here is the following snipp

**Asynchronous request**

> If you use an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest, you receive a callback when
>   the data has been received. This lets the browser continue to work as
>   normal while your request is being handled.

What does that mean in your case line by line:

Write in console log

```
login_button_pressed(username, password){
  console.log('Seen in console .log');
```

By calling subscribe in the observable you are effectively starting an async call. This will be deferred and the `(data) => // do something with data` will execute when the response arrives. Since js is not really concurrent, this was happening so that it wouldn't make the page unresponsive.

```
this.auth.login(username, password)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe( data => {
    //do something with data },
  error => {
    //print error  
});
```

If the response comes immediatly, then the response event is raised before the next line, but that's totally random and in most production cases with the distance overhead the next console log will almost always execute first

```
   console.log(login function ended);
}
```

**How to solve**

First try to change first() to take(1).   first() throws an error when the event stream completes before emitting a single event, while take(1) does not.

Second, you can try to switch to a promise and await

```
await this.auth.login(username, password)
     .pipe(take().toPromise().then(
         (result) => // Do stuff with result 
     );
```

Comment: ok, so I made the login login_button_pressed(username, password) an async function and wait on a promise.
async login_button_pressed(usrname, pwd){
await this.auth.login(username,password).toPromise().then(result => {
      console.log(result);
});

console.log('login function ended');

}

I couldn't do take().toPromise() because I return an observable from calling auth.login in auth.ts

Different results: login function ended not displayed in console.

Comment: Different behavior, but still same situation where angular is not waiting for response. 

I tried take(1) and it did not work.